# Python execute multiline code from user input with exec()

Tags: python, input, exec

I want to execute python code taking user input.
My program works like this:

```
While True:
    order = input('Enter your python code here: ')
    exec(order)
```

I managed to do this with one line codes like:
`print('txt')`

To execute multiline code I use this, works fine

```
order = 'a=[1,2,3]\nfor i in a:\n\tprint(i)'

exec(order)
```

The problem comes when I want to do the same but from user input

```
InputOrder = input('Enter code Here: ')
```

Then I enter the same as before code as input:

```
a=[1,2,3]\nfor i in a:\n\tprint(i)
```

And then I run the code with
`exec(InputOrder)`
and I get the following error:

```
a=[1,2,3]\nfor i in a:\n\tprint(i)
          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
While True:
    order = input('Enter code ')
    exec(order)
```

With user input:

`a=[1,2,3]\nfor i in a:\n print(i)`

Comment: Are you only forgetting the the quotes in this post or in your code as well? you need to place all of a in quotes for it to be a string: `a="[1,2,3]\nfor i in a:\n print(i)"`

Comment: Also a side note: `\n` does not take care of indentation. Because a for loop needs to be indented, you need to add a tab-character: `"for i in a:\n\t print(i)"`

Comment: @sami-amer input() returns a string, so I think there's realy no need in doing that, I did it anyway just to try, this time I don't have the error but the code doesn't run, I don't see the output printing.
- In reference to the second comment I do it with identation but I forgot to include it in my question, thanks :)
-Thanks for the reply, it will be appreicated if you try to reproduce the code and test it